# setting up omniauth-browserid (Mozilla Persona) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, mozilla, browserid

using **Rails 3.2.9**

added to **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'omniauth-broswerid'
```

ran:

```
bundle
```

browse to my app, click *Login with Browserid* button.  Get the following error:

> No route matches [GET] "/auth/browser_id/callback"

what am I missing?

Comment: Ryan Bates at Railscasts made a really good (and concise) video tutorial about incorporating omniauth into rails. He covers this exact issue at 2:47 in the screencast. Here's a link to the typewritten version of the screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This To your routes files

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

Comment: your answer resolved the error and got me to the next error, I'll leave the resolution to that error to another question.  Thanks.